# Can Minimize get multiple minima producing the same objective value?

Tags: mathematical-optimization

```
Minimize[(x-1)^2(x-2)^2,x]
```

gives only the solution 1, and not 2 (the help does not seem to mention this issue)

In general, if I do not know how many minimizers I have, I guess I could use smthng like

```
FindInstance[(x - 1)^2 (x - 2)^2 < 10^(-10), x, 2]
```

but is there a way to force `NMinimize` to attempt to find two, three, or more solutions?

Comment: `sol = Minimize[(x - 1)^2 (x - 2)^2, x];
Solve[(x - 1)^2 (x - 2)^2 == sol[[1]], x]`

Comment: @cvgmt: Unfortunately, that fails on `f = Piecewise[{{Exp[-1/(x - 1)^2], x != 1}, {0, x == 1}}] + 
  Piecewise[{{Exp[-1/(x + 1)^2], x != -1}, {0, x == -1}}]` , whereas mine works.

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
h = 1;n=5; Table[Minimize[{(x - 1)^2 (x - 2)^2, x >= h*j && x <= h*(j + 1)},   x], {j, -n, n}]
```

> `{{900, {x -> -4}}, {400, {x -> -3}}, {144, {x -> -2}}, {36, {x -> \ -1}}, {4, {x -> 0}}, {0, {x -> 1}}, {0, {x -> 1}}, {0, {x ->  2}}, {4, {x -> 3}}, {36, {x -> 4}}, {144, {x -> 5}}}`

?

Play with `h` and `n` in need.

Comment: @cvgmt, user64494,   Thanks. I'm only interested in x=1 and x=2, which of course may be easily extracted from user64494's "search for the lions in  Sahara". I still find it hard to believe that Mathematica does not provide a command for  "searching  the lions in  Sahara" but maybe the solution of cvgmt is so natural (once you learn it :),  that Mathematica did not deem necessary to provide it.

Comment: If we choose to solve global optimization by  "searching for all the lions in Sahara",  maybe it's more efficient to look for all local optima, or rather Karush-Kuhn-Tucker points, since my original problem is multidimensional and has also constraints. My question seems to reduce to  finding all KKT points and then comparing them.

Comment: @florin: The [DirectSearch](https://www.maplesoft.com/Applications/Detail.aspx?id=101333) package of Maple may be of interest to you.

Comment: @florin: Also pay your attention to https://www.dropbox.com/s/jvbs34ndpi1sqjq/CDOS%20method.pdf?dl=0